# paths must precede expression

Tags: bash, 20.04

Although there are files ending with `txt`, I am not able to use `find` command to search them.

```
$ ls *.txt
backprop.txt 
bfs.txt 
streamcluster.txt
$ find . -name *.txt
find: paths must precede expression: `bfs.txt'
find: possible unquoted pattern after predicate `-name'?
$ find . -name txt
$
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [`find` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Base-Name-Patterns):

> **2.2.1 Base Name Patterns**
>
> Test: -name pattern 
> Test: -iname pattern 
> [...] 
> Notice that the wildcard **must be enclosed in quotes** in order to protect it from expansion by the shell. 
> [...]

So the command should be:

```
find . -name "*.txt"
```